# Cursor hitting "border" between differently sized monitors

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I'm not sure if I'll be to explain this right. I have a dual monitor display on Windows 7 and my left monitor (laptop) has a lower vertical resolution than the right monitor (regular LCD monitor). So obviously, if I stick these monitors together, there's a part in the upper-left corner of my LCD monitor where cursor cannot go to the other monitor. I remember there was a trick to make this gap disappear, and make it seem like the monitors are of equal height.

Any suggestions?

By the way, I am also using UltraMon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure there's no way to make it seamless from the smaller to the larger screen.

If you right click on desktop, choose Personalize, Display Settings, you can drag the smaller screen higher or lower in relation to the bigger screen to determine exactly where you can cross over from one to the other.

I'm not sure if UltraMon has any settings like that.

Edit:  I just installed UltraMon beta version.  The beta version had a Display Settings panel that does that same thing.  You can change the relative position of the monitors to one another in order to control what areas will be blocked/open for crossover.

Answer (score 5):

[DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) has an option that automatically moves the mouse to the nearest matching area on the next monitor, making it appear to move smoothly between them.

[image]

Comment: That solution is working, however this feature is now available for the paid PRO version only. The installer will always install 30 days trial period, i.e you can try it also in the test version. Anybody found a free solution?

Answer (score 0):

all you do is go in to the resolution settings and you drag the monitor with the cursor and swop it round.

Answer (score 0):

Only free solution seems to be to optimize the position in the Windows 10 resolution configuration, i.e. move the monitors with the lower resolution to a height that minimize the blocking in daily use...

[image]

Comment: This is a better free tool:

https://superuser.com/a/1142011/134532