# How can I make the cursor in Windows with a multiple monitor setup behave like it's moving between all monitors having the same resolution?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution

I just added a new 4k monitor to my setup, bringing my total to 3. My problem is that windows "thinks" that the monitors are physically the relative sizes they are in the display settings, when they're really only an inch different (the 4k is 28" and the 2 1080s are 27").  This makes moving between the monitors a bit of a pain, since the mouse stops at the monitor edge when going from display 1 to either of the other 2.  The cursor also jumps to the middle of the screen when moving from either 1080 to the 4k.  Is there a way to get them to "line up" to the point where the cursor behaves like it's moving between monitors that have the same resolution?

[image: Screencap of the display settings]

System setup:
nVidia GTX 970
Intel Core i7 4790K
16Gb ram
Windows 10 Pro 64 bit

Comment: I totally fail your pain on this. I has a 24 inch FHD and 27 inch UHD monitors with the same issue in the past.

Comment: You can set custom resolutions in Nvidia Control Panel.

I don't know if this will work for making it more smooth between switching monitors but if you set them all at the same res it might work!

Comment: The only way to do it would be to run the 4k monitor at the lower resolution, but that's obviously not something you'd want to do.

Comment: Best idea might be to ditch the 2 small monitors and get another matching 4k monitor. It's much easier to work with matched monitors.

Comment: There is a simple way, program an application to adjust mouse speed in different monitor, I will do it for you if I have time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mouse cursor on multiple screens with different PPI](http://superuser.com/questions/1051269/mouse-cursor-on-multiple-screens-with-different-ppi)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cursor hitting “border” between differently sized monitors](http://superuser.com/questions/29552/cursor-hitting-border-between-differently-sized-monitors)

Answer (score 3):

Found this solution on a different [thread](https://superuser.com/a/1142011/), originally from Steve:

> Perhaps LittleBigMouse could help you out? It's an alpha application, but it seems to be focusing on the issue you're having.
>
> Github: https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse
>
> Download (Releases): https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse/releases

I have been using it myself with a 4K UHD monitor and a 1080p Full HD monitor and this does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't.

Computers don't know about the physical size of the monitors: only know about the virtual size (that is, the size in pixels).

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, the most reasonable one would be to enable what Nvidia calls DSR, on AMD side I believe is called super resolution, that will allow you to run your monitors on higher than native resolution, tricking the OS into thinking they are all 4k, depending on your work load you would even benefit from the 'extra' virtual space or it might not.
You could also rearrange both of the small monitors one above the other (bring #3 down in line with #2).

What I personally would do is flip those smaller monitors in portrait mode, one in each side, highly recommend you try it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to turn down the resolution of the 4k. This will fulfill your wish for it to behave like a 1080p monitor.

If you want to keep your resolutions, though, there is a more sloppy/glitchy alternative that involves some coding. You could write a program that detects your mouse cursor's position and, when you cross the screenborder, jumps it to (`y_pos`/`y_res_old`)`*y_res_new` (where `y_res_old` is the vertical resolution of the monitor you went out of, and y_res_new of the one you moved the mouse into). This could be glitchy, but with your processor, it might be so fast that you won't even notice.

I recommend only doing this if the cursor is within 5 or so pixels of the screen border, that way cursor stuttering is reduced to the transition parts.

TL;DR: if you don't want to delve into some programming, or commission a nerd to do it, you are left without choices - turn down resolution or leave it.

Comment: I wrote a very basic python script, if you are interested. It works for me with 2 monitors, though sometimes the cursor gets stuck if it is too close to the top/bottom when transitioning, if you are ok with that.